# Projecting world coordinates to screen coordinates issue - points disappear when origin not in view

Tags: c++, 2d, ogre, projection, viewport

I am trying to implement a 2d line drawing effect on a 3d mesh using Ogre. In order to do so, I perform silhouette detection on the lines of the object (this works) and then project these lines from world to screen coordinates.

Here is the code I use for converting the coordinates:

```
            bool toDeviceCoordinates(Ogre::Vector3 &result, Ogre::Vector3 &point,Ogre::Camera *camera)
            {
                if(!camera->isVisible(point))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                Ogre::Vector4 p(point.x,point.y,point.z,1);

                p = camera->getViewMatrix()*p;
                p = camera->getProjectionMatrix()*p;

                result = Ogre::Vector3(p.x,p.y,p.z);
                result /= p.w;

                return true;
            }
```

To draw these points to the screen I just pass them through the shader like so:

```
            gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
```

This works fine except when the origin of the scene is not visible.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem:

The shader was the culprit - seems it didn't like me skipping the application of the modelviewprojection matrix.

Instead, I applied the above function to convert my points to screen space.
I then did my calculations on it - extruding more vertices from it etc. I then applied the inverse matrix operations to those points to return them to world space.
These points were then passed to the shader and instead of:

```
gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
```

I use the more correct:

```
gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
```

So in essence here is my process:
world -> screen -> extrude points -> world -> screen